# Pass a function as a parameter between classes

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, parameter-passing

I have two Unity based classes, of which one represents the Player object and the other represents a powerup which should be able to manipulate the player.

My idea is to encapsulate the player manipulation operations within a method which can be passed to the player object, e.g. when the Player collides with the powerup.

These manipulations can include simple field and property changes (health points), but also possibly Coroutines (automatic firing or a shield with a time interval).

Currently, my player class holds all powerup related operations within itself, and calls them based on a string that gets passed from the powerup object upon collision:

PlayerController.cs

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<string, UnityAction> powerupMethods;

    // ...

    public void ActivatePowerUp(string name)
    {
        Invoke(powerUpMethods[name]);
    }
}
```

Powerup.cs

```
public class Powerup : MonoBehaviour
{
   private string _name;

   // ...

   private void OnCollision2D(Collision col)
   {
       PlayerController p = col.collider.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
       if (p != null)
       {
           p.ActivatePowerup(_name);
       }
   }
}
```

My wish would be to eliminate all powerup related logic from the player object and keep it in the respective powerups.

Is there a technical possibility to contain such operations within a method that can be passed from the powerup object to the player object, something like this? The best case would be that the player object could access private fields within the method.

```cs
// Powerup.cs
public void Ability()
{
    // Do stuff with Player object, even private fields
    // e.g. player._health++;
    // But also activate self-based Coroutines
    // e.g. StartCoroutine(CoroutineMethod());
}

private IEnumerator CoroutineMethod()
{
    // e.g. auto fire for 5 seconds
}

private void OnCollision2D(Collision2D col)
{
    PlayerController p = col.collider.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    if (p != null) p.Invoke(Ability());
}
```

Comment: Your example code at the end is confusing, do you want to pass the `Player` object to the `Powerup` (as a parameter - in this case what is the problem here?) or do you want to pass a function to another class (e.g.: as a callback)?

Comment: I updated my intended code.

Comment: And I'm also open for better suggestions regarding the handling of such code and components.

Comment: If you really want to pass a function then you can use `delegate`, see the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/ - as for "better suggestions" that would mostly depend on your very specific scenario, so it's hard to give general advice (passing methods as parameters is an acceptable option in many cases)

Comment: I made some experiments with delegates, but I think the biggest problem would be to pass an IEnumerator function to start it as a Coroutine. Or is that supposed to be possible as well?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there is a problem - do you have an actual error (if yes then please post the code and exact error message)? And you can pass pretty much anything as a parameter, it's just a matter of figuring out what the parameter type needs to be.

Comment: i would just let the power up manipulate the player stats on collision and then destroy itself. For things like guns i would add them to a inventory like list and let the list affect the player based on whats currently inside

Comment: The problem regarding the Coroutine was that after I (allegedly) pass the function and the Coroutine, I order the powerup to be destroyed, which in turn looks like the coroutine is cancelled as a result of the destruction. I don't have an explicit error, but instead of iterating the auto fire multiple times, only one projectile is fired.

Comment: FYI, I tested my current code with the Destroy method called at the end of the Coroutine, and everything works fine. But that in turn means I have to fix the powerup to not interfere with the gameplay (unset sprite, remove collider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by saying I think that passing a reference to a method is the wrong solution for this case. I would simply pass a reference of the `Player` to the method inside the `Powerup` class.

Having said that, using delegates is an important and powerful part of .Net programming, so I thought I'd better give you a little introduction to it - so here goes:

It's possible and even quite easy to pass references to methods around, using delegates. Since the .Net 2.0 version you can use [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Func`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) predefined system delegates for that.
There are plenty of them, ranging between no arguments to 16 generic arguments, meaning it's going to be very rare for you to have to write a delegate the old fashion way like we did in .Net 1.1. (a long, long time ago)

All `Action` delegates represents `void` methods, and all `Func` delegates represents method that returns a value. It's quite easy (and a very common practice) to create a method that accepts an `Action` or a `Func` as an argument and invokes it - and many of the built in classes and extension methods of the .Net framework do that, such as [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_ForEach_System_Action__0__) and linq methods are based almost entirely on `Func` delegates.

Let's take linq to object `Any()` method source code for example (since it's simple):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, it takes a `Func<TSource, bool>` and invokes it on every item in the `IEnumerable` until it finds an item that the predicate returned `true` about it, or it gets to the end of the `IEnumerable` and returns `false`.